# Ship Python based product with Anaconda on windows?

Tags: python

I have a python service that runs on anaconda (using a lot of `conda install`) and a C# UI. Are there any restrictions for shipping anaconda (not modified) + installed packages + my service as a paid not opensource product?

Comment: The answer depends on all the involved licenses and (to some degree) which packages are used as python imports and which are called as executables. Currently, your question has too little information to be answerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the restrictions come from the licenses of anaconda and the installed packages - you will have to abide by them when you distribute them, modified or not. You need to check them all and specifically you should check that none has a non-commercial clause or license.

You will also want to make sure that people get the license information for each package and that they can obtain the sources to those software where they have a right to obtain it. Usually it must not be more complicated than getting the binaries.

While anaconda itself is open source, Read carefully about distribution of bundles of the packages as taken from anaconda.com. The TOS for *individual* end users explicitly say that no-one should get the impression that they endorse derived endevours. I find no text on commercial usage...